# Getting audio frequency and then drawing it onto a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How would I get a html5 audio's sound frequency and then draw it onto a canvas?

Comment: Do you mean from an `<audio>` tag, or with a webkitAudioContext javascript object? In anycase, first, you gotta load the sample data, then you have to do an FFT on it, then you have to draw the bars that correspond to the level for each of the frequency bins. Lots of work in the FFT, best you look for a library to do that step.

Comment: No need to equalize, webkitAudio can do the frequency analysis for you. Search the web for tutorials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the new [Web Audio API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/) to get FFT processed data (as well as sample data).

Web Audio API is a low-level highly optimized API that is supported directly in the browser. But a couple of notes:

- It's in working status (not complete)
- It's not [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api) cross-browser yet (but is in the decent browsers).

Excerpt taken for the first link below:

```
function setupAudioNodes() {

    // setup a javascript node
    javascriptNode = context.createJavaScriptNode(2048, 1, 1);
    // connect to destination, else it isn't called
    javascriptNode.connect(context.destination);

    // setup a analyzer
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
    analyser.fftSize = 512;

    // create a buffer source node
    sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
    sourceNode.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
}
```

(note that some of these examples are probably written with webkit prefixed calls so the odds are that you need to use Chrome to see them but Web Audio API is also available in other browsers).

Some examples of spectrum analyzers:
http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound
http://tx81z.blogspot.mx/2012/10/quick-project-d3-html5-web-audio.html
http://www.storiesinflight.com/jsfft/visualizer_webaudio/